# my movies are not converting properly

Tags: windows-vista

when i try converting a film it goes through the full process it even says operation complete afther burning but disks still turn out to be blank i have used convert x and imtoo avi convert to dvd how can i solve this

Comment: How are you determining that the disks are still blank?

Comment: when i am tryin them on computer and the it says its got all the free space that the disk has and try to play it but it trys to format then i try in dvd but it says blank disk

Comment: This may be a silly question. Are you sure you burnt the converted data to the disc? It is possible that ConvertXtoDVD only converted and saved the files on your hard disk and it didn't burn it.

Comment: What program are you using and what options do you set?

Comment: To make sure someone sees a comment add "@[username]" into the comment (e.g. @ChrisF)

Comment: It would be helpful if you reference a http://www.videohelp.com/ or similar guide. This question is way to vague - too many variables and moving parts - to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following a guide from http://videohelp.com for the tools you have. While the guides do not always offer the "best" way to do something, the steps provided work.